# Grep to exclude certain sequences

Tags: bash, shell

So I have text such as

```
[headline - https://www.rfa.org/vietnamese/news/programs/ListenerForum/corresponding-reply-103114-ha-10312014121120.html]
[date - https://www.rfa.org/vietnamese/news/programs/ListenerForum/corresponding-reply-103114-ha-10312014121120.html]
```

Then I have texts such as

```
[VĐX, Chương 1, Nxb Thái Độ 1970]
```

How do I grep and get every instance that starts with `[` but those are NOT `headline` and `date`?

`grep "\/[ <everything but not headline and date>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
grep -Ev '^\[(headline|date) ' Input_File
```